# JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, object

I can easily create and object in a lot of different. For example like this:

```
var myObject = {
    myFunction: function () {
        return "";
    }
};
```

So if I alert this object I get something this:

```
[object Object]
```

Now I'm if I alert the `NaN` object I get this:

```
NaN
```

And I can still call function from it:

```
alert(NaN.hasOwnProperty().toString());
```

So my question is how can I create a object like the `NaN` object?

1. If I alert it, it should return something like `myObject`
2. I should be able to create and call functions on it like `myObject.myFunction();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only objects that are created using a constructor function get their class name displayed using `console.log()`, as shown in @Esalijia's answer.

Even then, it'll be the *class name* that's displayed, not the name of whatever variable you happened to assign the object to.

Adding a `toString()` method to the object will however change the output of the `alert()` function, since that always looks for the presence of that method and use it if it exists.

So, writing:

```
var myObj = {
    toString: function() { return "boo"; }
}
alert(myObj)
```

will show `boo` in the alert box, instead of `[Object object]`.

Answer (score 3):

```
    function MyObject(){}

    MyObject.prototype = {

        toString: function(){
            return "myObject";
        },

        myFunction: function(){

        }

    };

var myObject = new MyObject();

alert( myObject );
//myObject
```

Comment: No but it fills these criteria: `If I log it it should return something like myObject
I should be able to create and call functions on it like myObject.myFunction();`

Comment: Sorry but I don't want it return `> MyObject` I want it to return `MyObject` like the `NaN` object does it. I edited my question  to make it more clear.

Comment: @micha NaN is not an object. What makes you think it is?

Comment: @Esailija NaN is an object for me because you can loop through it.

Comment: @micha you don't loop through `NaN`, you loop through a `Number` object that is created on the fly when you pass `NaN` to `for..in`.

Answer (score 2):

```
alert(NaN.hasOwnProperty().toString()); // says false. 
alert(typeof NaN); //says it is a number
```

So, I don't think NaN is an Object and It's datatype is a number.

**For more info**: NaN means Not-a-Number. Even datatype is number, it is not a number. When any mathematical calculation can't return number,it returns NaN. The isNaN() function determines whether a value is an illegal number (Not-a-Number).This function returns true if the value is NaN, and false if not.

For example,

```
var num=35;
var num2=num/'asg';
console.log(num2); //returns NaN
```

Comment: `NaN` is a number that is "Not A Number"

Comment: `NaN` will be returned when you do an impossible JavaScript operation.  For me NaN is an object because you can loop through it.

Comment: @AndrewD, micha. You more are correct ! It's something like exception. NaN is returned when impossible mathematical operation.

Answer (score 1):

`NaN` is a number primitive, not an object.  Like all primitives, it is converted to an object when you use the `.` operator to access a property or method that exists on the creator class's `prototype`.

To display properties available for primitives, either convert them to an object, or use `console.dir()`

```
console.dir(NaN);
console.log(Object(NaN));
```

All primitives behave this way, when you call `console.log` on any of the following, they exhibit the same behaviour:

```
console.log("Hello");
console.log(1);
console.log(true);
```

Yet, you can access properties on them like normal objects:

```
"Hello".length;
1 .toString();
true.valueOf();
```

Comment: +1 Nice answer but can't I create a new "native" thing like `#ffffff` with properties `#ffffff.rgb();` (Not as string)

Comment: @micha: really, the whole premise of your question was a problem because you thought `NaN` was an object, which made it difficult to answer for all those who tried.

Comment: Now I think every JavaScript variable is an object (not in real but for me)